# Gitlab - An error occurred while fetching the job

Tags: docker, configuration, gitlab, http-status-code-403, gitlab-ce

I'm running the latest version of Gitlab Community Edition within a Docker container behind a jwilder nginx Proxy. The Rack Attack Gem is disabled by configuration but when a Gitlab Runner job failed to authenticate against the registry (which is on the same domain but with port 4567) a red banner occurs within Gitlab:

> An error occurred while fetching the job

When I refresh the Gitlab instance I just see 403 HTTP status which tells me, that I'm no longer allowed to access Gitlab. Even when I login with a different user in another Browser window (even a private window).

I'm not sure what's going on here and are willing to share a much information as possible. But I don't really know where to start because the only thing which makes sense was the Rack Attack plugin which is disabled.

I tried to build a new version of the docker container by throwing the current one away. I also cleared the bound redis instance just to ensure rack attack has really no affect on the current behaviour.

**docker info:**

```
Containers: 58
 Running: 21
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 37
Images: 615
Server Version: 18.09.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 1313
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: ...
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: ...
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8  
 SubnetSize: 24
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: ...
 Manager Addresses:
  ...:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9754871865f7fe2f4e74d43e2fc7ccd237edcbce
runc version: 96ec2177ae841256168fcf76954f7177af9446eb
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-42-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 31.28GiB
Name: myserver.example.com
ID: JB7Q:3MNW:GJ6Q:...:EI5K:NKU3
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 location=cloud
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    container_name: gitlab
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${REPOSITORY_HOST},${REGISTRY_HOST}
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${REPOSITORY_HOST},${REGISTRY_HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
      - GITLAB_REGISTRY_ENABLED=true
      - GITLAB_REGISTRY_HOST=${REPOSITORY_HOST}:4567
      - GITLAB_REGISTRY_CERT_PATH=/certs/registry.example.com.chain.pem
      - GITLAB_REGISTRY_KEY_PATH=/certs/registry.example.com.key
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    expose:
      - 80
      - 22
    ports:
      - '2222:22'
      - '4567:4567'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
      - '/srv/www/nginx-proxy/certs:/certs:ro'
    logging:
      driver: gelf
      options:
        gelf-address: ${GELF_HOST}

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    command:
    - --loglevel warning
    volumes:
    - /srv/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis:Z
    logging:
      driver: gelf
      options:
        gelf-address: ${GELF_HOST}

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

**gitlab.rb** configuration:

```
external_url 'https://repository.example.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@repository.example.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'Gitlab'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'noreply@repository.example.com'
gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = true
gitlab_rails['redis_host'] = "redis"
gitlab_rails['redis_port'] = 6379
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25 
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "changeme"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "changeme"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "example.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = false 
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'
registry_external_url 'https://repository.example.com:4567'
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
registry['enable'] = true
redis['enable'] = true
nginx['listen_port'] = 80 
nginx['listen_https'] = false
registry_nginx['enable'] = true 
registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 4567
registry_nginx['listen_https'] = true
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/certs/registry.example.com.crt"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/certs/registry.example.com.key"
registry_nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['*', '[::]']
registry_nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
  "Host" => "$http_host",
  "X-Real-IP" => "$remote_addr",
  "X-Forwarded-For" => "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
  "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
}
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: php:7.3-fpm-alpine

cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/
  - node_modules/

stages:
- build
- test
- release

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  NIGHTLY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  LATEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME:latest

before_script:
- sh .gitlab/docker_install.sh > /dev/null
- docker info
- cp .env.example .env
- sed -i "s/CACHE_DRIVER=.*/CACHE_DRIVER=array/" .env
- sed -i "s/SESSION_DRIVER=.*/SESSION_DRIVER=array/" .env
- php composer.phar install
- php artisan key:generate
- npm install
- npm run prod

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  - docker build --pull -t $NIGHTLY_IMAGE .
  - docker build -t $NIGHTLY_IMAGE -f ./docker/php/Dockerfile.production --pull .
  - docker push $NIGHTLY_IMAGE
  - docker push $LATEST_IMAGE

test:7.2:
  stage: test
  image: php:7.2-fpm-alpine
  script:
  - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
  - npm run test

test:7.3:
  stage: test
  image: php:7.3-fpm-alpine
  script:
  - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
  - npm run test

release:
  stage: release
  script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  - docker pull $TEST_IMAGE
  - docker tag $TEST_IMAGE $RELEASE_IMAGE
  - docker push $RELEASE_IMAGE
  only:
  - master
```

**.gitlab/docker_install.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

[[ ! -e /.dockerenv ]] && exit 0

set -xe

apk add --update \
    docker \
    libpq \
    libpng-dev \
    jpeg-dev \
    freetype-dev \
    libxrender \
    fontconfig \
    libxext-dev \
    openldap-dev \
    git \
    nodejs nodejs-npm \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    curl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql mysqli gd zip ldap pcntl

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

curl --location --output /usr/local/bin/phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit

curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
  && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

So currently I'm not able to login to Gitlab with ANY user. It must be possible to login again and I would like to understand what's going on here and why Gitlab blocks every login/request with a forbidden response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a problem with Redis. Some postings mentioned a rack attack ban and I was pretty sure this wasn't the case because it's disabled by default, but after deleting flushing all Redis keys, I was able to use Gitlab again without 403 Forbidden errors.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37090

So i did the following in my case:

```
$ docker exec -it redis bash
$ redis-cli
$ FLUSHALL
```

Comment: So, deleting the redis keys helps, but there is still no rack attack key inside.. Have to investigate further.